# bad tree object при push на Github

Tags: git

Помогите спасти репозиторий. 
При попытке отправить из VS на github локального репозитория который ведется уже 3 года. Ранее на github  не отправлялся был только локально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после запроса

> git reflog --all

все идет ровно но в самых первых коммитах видим 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что то подсказывает что так быть не должно.

Причем ошибки 3-х годичной давности 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с

> git reset --hard

все хорошо , а

> git status

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файла **ebc8e5ecfa70852aaef3ed8329ff2d75ab897a29** нету. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Куда копать не знаю. Терять 3 года коммитов не хочется...

Comment: есть много причин. К примеру, некоторым людям помогает перезапуск IDE (vscode). я бы для начала сделал копию локального репозитория (на всякий случай), также сделал копию с гитхаба (то есть, clone). А потом проверил локальный репозиторий с помощью https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck.  скорее всего нужно будет просто скопировать недостающие файлы и будет готово.

Comment: прикрепил ответ по git fsck --full

Comment: У вас файлы битые. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37740711/9435985) человек написал как он справился, но я уверен, что это какая-то полумера, что-то будет работать, а что-то нет. Есть копия репы? Тогда удалите каталог `.git` и снова сделайте `git init ... git add remote ... git fetch ... git reset`, примерно так это должно выглядеть, если нужны детали, я напишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если поврежденный коммит где-то очень давно, то можно сделать клон, содержащий информацию только после него, и эту копию уже отправить на github.

Для этого есть параметр `--depth` указывающий сколько коммитов вглубь брать.

При клонировании локально указывается протокол `file://` и путь к подпапке `.git` репозитория.

`git clone --depth 100 "file:///path/to/repo/.git" "/path/to/repo2/"`

вычитает историю на 100 коммитов.

Позднее можно увеличить глубину истории командой fetch с новой глубиной

`git fetch --depth 200`

Так постепенно можно увеличивать глубину, пока не дойдете до ошибки.

**UPD**

Еще можно вытянуть историю до поврежденного коммита, если удастся найти его хеш.

`git fetch origin <hash>` вытянет историю до указанного коммита включительно, а

`bit branch old <hash>` создаст на нем ветку `old`, что предотвратит удаление этих коммитов сборщиком мусора, и позволит к ним обращаться.

**UPD2**

Как найти хеш:

При помощи git log во втором репозитории находите последний выкачанный коммит и его хеш.

Командой `git cat-file commit <hash>` получаете информацию о коммите в следующем виде:

```
tree <hash>
parent <hash>
authot <имя> <почта> <unixtimestamp>
committer <имя> <почта> <unixtimestamp>

Сообщение коммита
```

parent'ов может быть несколько, если это merge или не быть, если это первый коммит в истории.

В данном случае parent'ом будет поврежденный коммит.

Переходите в изначальный репозиторий и выполняя `git cat-file` уже от этого коммита, записываете parent'а.

Пробуете сделать его fetch. С большой долей вероятности не сработает, так как если файл (blob) или папка (tree) не меняется, то они будут одинаковы у разных коммитов.

Повторяем `git cat-file`, взять paretn, пока не найдем неповрежденный коммит.

Comment: Спасибо. По вашей методе удалось спасти 140/292 коммитов. Ошибка где-то в середине судя по всему на 141 коммите. Потом еще поэкспериментирую. но Это уже результат )

Comment: @Max, гляньте дополнение ответа

Comment: "если удастся найти его хеш"  - понять бы как искать

Comment: @Max, дополнил еще раз